# Creating method with a formal parameter to set a value and a method to return a string

Tags: java, string, methods

I am currently working on a lab that requires me to add additional code to code found in my textbook. I tried searching for a solution for my problems here, but I was unable to find one.

Our instructions for the lab are such:

> Add another instance variable to the Dog class called weight which is an int variable.
>
> Add another method to the Dog class called setWeight() which has an int formal parameter which sets the weight of the dog.
>
> Add another method to the Dog class called getSize() that returns a String.  It will use the weight of the dog as follows:
>
> If the dog is less than 30 pounds, it returns the `String` *small*.  If the dog is between 30 and 60 pounds, it returns the `String` *medium*.  If the dog is over 60 pounds, it returns the `String` *large*.
>
> Add the following code to the DogDemo class:

```
Dog otto = new Dog();
otto.name = "Otto";
otto.age = 7;
otto.breed = "German Shepherd";
otto.setWeight(50);
System.out.println();
otto.writeOutput();
System.out.println("Otto is a " + otto.getSize() + " dog.");
```

So far, I have not been able to figure out how to properly setup both the `setWeight()` method and the `getSize()` method, and I'm also unsure if I properly defined the instance variable weight. Here is my code so far.

```
package dogdemo;

public class Dog
{
public String name;
public String breed;
public int age;
public int weight;
public int getSize()
{
    if (weight < 30) {
        getSize = ("small");
    } else {
        if (weight >= 30 && weight <=60)
            getSize=("medium");
    } else {
            getSize=("large");
            }
}
public void writeOutput()
{
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Breed: " + breed);
    System.out.println("Age in calendar years: " +
    age);
    System.out.println("Age in human years: " +
    getAgeInHumanYears());
    System.out.println();
}
public int getAgeInHumanYears()
{
    int humanAge = 0;
    if (age <= 2)
    {
        humanAge = age * 11;
    }
    else
    {
        humanAge = 22 + ((age-2) * 5);
    }
        return humanAge;
    }
}
```

Here is the other class code that actually outputs the information.

```
package dogdemo;

public class DogDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Dog balto = new Dog();
    balto.name = "Balto";
    balto.age = 8;
    balto.breed = "Siberian Husky";
    balto.writeOutput();
    Dog scooby = new Dog();
    scooby.name = "Scooby";
    scooby.age = 42;
    scooby.breed = "Great Dane";
    System.out.println(scooby.name + " is a " +
    scooby.breed + ".");
    System.out.print("He is " + scooby.age +
    " years old, or ");
    int humanYears = scooby.getAgeInHumanYears();
    System.out.println(humanYears + " in human years.");
}
}
```

As you can see, in public class Dog, I tried my hand at creating a getSize() method but did not really know what I was doing. I did not even try to create a setWeight() method as I am totally unsure how to code that. For creating the instance variable weight, I made it public, but I'm thinking it may have to be private.

Thanks in advance and all help appreciated.

Comment: @KennethClark that doesn't meet the requirements - **Add another method to the Dog class called getSize() that returns a String.**

Comment: Walrus, I think you can answer your own question, if you got this far without any extra help. Hints - Make weight private. How would you then set/get the weight of a dog ? If you make weight public, then how do you prevent someone from entering negative or too much weight ? The answer will become clear to you when you think about these questions and try to convert them into code.

Comment: @DavidPostill apologies you are right , was not paying attention, modify size Method to return a string using weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what your problem with `setWeight()` is.

It's quite simple :

```
public void setWeight(int weight)
{
    this.weight = weight;
}
```

As for `getSize()`, you got the logic mostly right, but you have to return a String.

```
public String getSize()
{
    if (weight < 30) {
       return "small";
    } else {
        if (weight >= 30 && weight <=60) {
            return "medium";
        } else {
            return "large";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's defined fine. But the class attributes should be with `private` modifier like this.

Here is how it looks like,

```
public class Dog{
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private int age;
    private int weight;

    public void setWeight(int weight){ // parameter name is same as the attribute name
        this.weight = weight; //Using this keyword we address the attribute.
    }

    public String getSize(){
        if (weight < 30) {
            return "small";
        } else if (weight  >= 30 && weight <=60)
            return "medium";            
        } else {
            return "large";                
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not properly defined the properties of your class Try this one

```
      public class Dog
    {
    public static String name;
    public static String breed;
    public static int age;
    public static int weight;
    public static String size;


    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public static void setName(String name) {
        Dog.name = name;
    }
    public static String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }
    public static void setBreed(String breed) {
        Dog.breed = breed;
    }
    public static int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public static void setAge(int age) {
        Sample3.age = age;
    }
    public static int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public static void setWeight(int weight) {
        Sample3.weight = weight;
    }
    public static String getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public static void setSize(String size) {
        Dog.size = size;
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
setName("Browny");
setBreed("BlaBla");
setAge(12);
setWeight(32);
writeOutput();
}
    public static void writeOutput()
    {
if(getWeight()<30){
setSize("small");
}
if(getWeight()>30 && getWeight()<60){
setSize("medium");
}
if(getWeight()>60){
setSize("Large");
}
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Breed: " + breed);
         System.out.println("Age:: " + age);
       System.out.println("Weight: " + weight);
       System.out.println("Size: " + size);

    }

    }
```

I Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Below work code:

```
public class Dog{
    public String name;
    public String breed;
    public int age;
    public int weight; //Good way replace access to private and use getter and setter.
    /**
     * It setter for weight variable.
     */
    public void setWeight(int weight){
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    /**
    * It getter for weight variable. I would replace to getWeight().
    * Furthermore your sample contain error because return type is int
    */
    public String getSize() {
        if (weight < 30) return "small";
        else {
            if (weight >= 30 && weight <=60) {
                return "medium";
            } else {
                return "large";
            }
        }
    }
    /**
    * Note, I add output of weight. Good way is rename this method to toString()
    * Read it http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_tostring.htm
    */
    public void writeOutput() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Breed: " + breed);
        System.out.println("Age in calendar years: " + age);
        System.out.println("Age in human years: " + getAgeInHumanYears());
        System.out.println("Weight: " + getSize());
        System.out.println();
    }
    public int getAgeInHumanYears() {
        int humanAge = 0;
        if (age <= 2) humanAge = age * 11;
        else humanAge = 22 + ((age-2) * 5);
        return humanAge;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dog otto = new Dog();
        otto.name = "Otto";
        otto.age = 7;
        otto.breed = "German Shepherd";
        otto.setWeight(50);
        System.out.println();
        otto.writeOutput();
        System.out.println("Otto is a " + otto.getSize() + " dog.");
        Dog balto = new Dog();
        balto.name = "Balto";
        balto.age = 8;
        balto.breed = "Siberian Husky";
        balto.setWeight(20);
        balto.writeOutput();
        Dog scooby = new Dog();
        scooby.name = "Scooby";
        scooby.age = 42;
        scooby.breed = "Great Dane";
        scooby.setWeight(70);
        scooby.writeOutput();
        System.out.println(scooby.name + " is a " + scooby.breed + ".");
        System.out.print("He is " + scooby.age + " years old, or ");
        int humanYears = scooby.getAgeInHumanYears();
        System.out.println(humanYears + " in human years.");
    }
}
```

Test it:

```
~/tmp $ javac Dog.java 
~/tmp $ java Dog
Name: Otto
Breed: German Shepherd
Age in calendar years: 7
Age in human years: 47
Weight: medium

Name: Balto
Breed: Siberian Husky
Age in calendar years: 8
Age in human years: 52
Weight: small

Name: Scooby
Breed: Great Dane
Age in calendar years: 42
Age in human years: 222
Weight: large

Scooby is a Great Dane.
He is 42 years old, or 222 in human years.
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to define the Dog bean class. Normally we have to define all instant variables as private variables and then we have to define getters and setters to access those variables.
Then we have to write a demo class for run the application.

Dog bean class

```
public class Dog {

  private String name;
  private String breed;
  private int age;
  private int weight;

  public Dog() {
  }

  public Dog(String name, String breed, int age, int weight) {
      this.name = name;
      this.breed = breed;
      this.age = age;
      this.weight = weight;
  }

  public String getName() {
      return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  }

  public String getBreed() {
      return breed;
  }

  public void setBreed(String breed) {
      this.breed = breed;
  }

  public int getAge() {
      return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
  }

  public int getWeight() {
      return weight;
  }

  public void setWeight(int weight) {
      this.weight = weight;
  }

  public String getSize() {
      if (weight < 30) return "small";
      else if (weight >= 30 && weight < 60) return "medium";
      else return "large";
  }

  public int getAgeInHumanYears() {
      int humanAge = 0;
      if (age <= 2) humanAge = getAge() * 11;
      else humanAge = 22 + ((getAge() - 2) * 5);
      return humanAge;
  }

  public void writeOutput(){
      System.out.println("Name: " +getName());
      System.out.println("Breed: " + getBreed());
      System.out.println("Age:: " + getAge());
      System.out.println("Weight: " + getAge());
      System.out.println("Size: " + getSize());
      System.out.println("Age in human age : "+ getAgeInHumanYears());
  }
```

}

Dog demo class

```
public class DogDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Dog dog = new Dog("Jason", "Great Dane", 12, 65);
      dog.writeOutput();
  }
```

}

If you use a IDE to run this application, simply compile and run this application. If you use command prompt to run this application, create separate two java file and name both files in class name and add above codes into those file and compile both file using javac and run the DogDemo class file using java

Good Luck !!!!